# Why downvotes and retracted upvotes are not notified immediately?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications

Whenever I get downvoted or somebody retracts their upvotes on my answers/questions, I don't get notifications immediately. But it gets accumulated with the notification of the next positive rep. For example, if somebody downvotes my question/answer (I ll not get immediate notification) and somebody upvotes any of my answers, it will show `+8` in the notification.

Why am I not getting immediate notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We reserve real-time notifications for positive changes, not negative ones.

This is a long standing design decision - when something good happens, we want to let you know immediately. Something bad? Not as quickly...

Comment: Oh, what if I wanted to react to the "comment-less downvotes" quickly?

Comment: It isn't hidden. We still show them in the dropdown, we just don't notify.

Comment: Yup, system is working fine. But unless I check manually, I will not get to know what happened.

Comment: This has been discussed before, BTW - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224032/140505

Comment: Can we make this a configurable option in the profile?

Comment: You can make that a feature request...

Comment: Thanks :) Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252909/1903116