# Configurable option for negative reputation notification

Tags: feature-request

Following my [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252900/1903116), can we have a configurable option in our profile pages to get notifications for negative changes in the reputation?

When it is enabled, we will get immediate notifications for the negative reputation changes (downvotes/retracted upvotes), otherwise it will continue to work as it is now (negative reputations will be clubbed with the next positive reputation and notified immediately).

Comment: I didn't downvote, however [voting is different on Meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Someone thought that your _feature-request_ is not useful so he/she expressed it using the downvote.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Thanks :) `On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.`

Comment: Maybe the downvoters wanted to test if this feature already existed. Based on your response we assume it does... :)

Comment: @rene: hehe, except there is no reputation change on meta..

Comment: @rene But I responded because I was editing the question when I got the downvote :-)

Comment: IIRC, You still get a notification if you click the button (and I think it turns green as well), but it doesn't show a number.

Comment: I've just been thinking about submitting the same feature request. Can we please do this? Should we bump this question?

Answer (score -5):

**No**, please don't.

I won't pretend I know for sure what Stack Overflow staff's motives are for this, but I will wholehearteadly disagree with whatever gets more attention to posts being downvoted.

People already react pretty badly to downvotes, and I don't think that having a red icon show up would help with that at all, be it only with the negative feedback emotion (in opposition to the positive feedback we get when seeing a green notification).

You can already see which of your posts were downvoted in the notification bar. If one's goal **truly** is to improve their posts, they can already do so by reading that.

On another topic, people, especially newcomers, go around witch hunting when they get downvoted. They often blame it on whoever had the mis-chance of commenting around the moment they see a downvote.

I would prefer not to draw even more attention to the downvotes.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous same as upvotes are. Nobody gets to know who has downvoted or upvoted my post including me.

Comment: ... Indeed @RBT. I don't exactly get what you mean. However, let me say it again: things like that just help people pinpoint who downvoted when. Which should not be encouraged. What else would it serve?

Comment: That's what I'm unable to understand as to how such alert mechanism will help me pin point the person who has downvoted me. If I get a notification that I've been downvoted then something is wrong with my post. So I will improve or remove my post rather than go hunting for the guy who has downvoted me. Isn't it?

Comment: @RBT ... people already ping other commenters randomly when they get downvoted, blaming anyone who has the mis chance to comment at the same time as they see a downvote. As for what you say, you can **already** see which posts you have which were downvoted. What more do you want, if your goal really is to improve them? I, for one, don't think that someone who is genuinely interested in improving need to see a downvote at the moment it happens to do so.