# Question Downvote/Flag Notification

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, downvotes, notifications

Could a new feature be implemented that the asker of a question is notified, when one of their questions are downvoted or flagged?

This way, question askers will have a chance to fix the issues in their question before more users flag/downvote, and the asker's site reputation is affected.
This method will also help new users avoid being banned from asking questions, and will also mean that less questions are deleted by moderators/users.

A simple notification in the users' Stack Exchange mailbox could be the difference between a bad question being deleted/downvoted by the community, or a bad question being turned into a good question from some simple edits.

A 'Heads up, your question has been flagged for..'-type notification would be useful, but not necessary, especially since most users seem to prefer downvoting questions, and not flagging or commenting on them.

A 'Heads up, your question was downvoted' would also be useful.

Comment: Don't you already get a "notification" for a downvote in the form of a rep change? Or does that not show up right away? (edit: realized that this won't apply if you're already at low rep...)

Comment: @user3580294 Nope. The 'rep change' icon turns red (and it is *very* easy to miss, since the colour is far too opaque), but there's no actual notification.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that the changing color of the rep icon would be enough, but guess not...

Comment: @user3580294 The colour change is not sufficient enough to be noticed, unless you are specifically looking for it (if you know what I mean..). This could just be one of the many issues with Stack Overflow's colour scheme. Another issue is the box that covers a code-block; I have to view my monitor from the side to see the box. This issue occurs on multiple monitors and computers, so I know it's not just me.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought I see a bright red "-2" whenever one of my answers gets downvoted... Are question votes done differently?

Comment: @user3580294 Not sure; I only ever see the positive changes to my reputation.

Comment: @Payeli Fine ;).

Comment: @Payeli Nope, I didn't get anything.

Comment: [Related post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252903/2982225)

Comment: Huh: *This is a long standing design decision - when something good happens, we want to let you know immediately. Something bad? Not as quickly...*. It'd be better if it were to be the other way round.

Comment: @Payeli See, this is *exactly* what I'm talking about. Someone downvoted this question, I did not get any notification, PLUS the user who did so has not commented to say WHY they downvoted it! This is exactly the issue here.

Comment: calm down, this is MSO not SO voting here is different. When your question is a feature-request the votes express agreement/disagreement with your request.

Comment: My question is - what if someone has too much time on hand and they decide to downvote and then upvote your question for fun for about 20 minutes.. what if there are two or more of the trolls?

Comment: @mehow I was merely pointing out the uncommon nack that many users have on here, that they downvote questions without commenting *why* they downvoted it. Such behavior isn't useful, and the asker of the question cannot be sure what to correct.

Comment: @mehow Good point, though there could be a 'deactivation', that if the question is voted down by the same user more than once, the asker of the question only is notified about it the first time.

Comment: but if you **ask a good question** from the start then receiving 1 or 2 negative votes would cause no harm...

Comment: @mehow I'm not talking about *me*, nor is this having a rant about *my experience*. My suggestion was that this feature, if implemented, would aid new users into learning what is acceptible on SO, and what's not.

Comment: I still don't think we should do anything else to help new users familiarize themselves with the site. If anyone is willing they will do anyway, don't point out the obvious..

Comment: @mehow It's just getting tiring submitting close votes (the majority of them get accepted) for questions that new users submit, for mainly problems like obvious code errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why downvotes and retracted upvotes are not notified immediately?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252900/why-downvotes-and-retracted-upvotes-are-not-notified-immediately)

Comment: @Cupcake My question is a feature request, and the question you pointed out is not. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configurable option for negative reputation notification](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252909/456814).

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reputation notifications already exist in several places, so I'm going to just address flags here...

A long, long time ago, users over a certain rep level could see flags on their posts. They weren't *notified* of them (notifications as we know them now didn't even exist) but if they looked they could see them.

...This led to a lot of unconstructive drama. You can't *do* anything about a flag, other than flag the post again; it was just a blinking red "SOMETHING IS WRONG" indicator.

> A simple notification in the users' Stack Exchange mailbox could be the difference between a bad question being deleted/downvoted by the community, or a bad question being turned into a good question from some simple edits.

Sure. So could a comment, or a downvote, or even closing or deletion. As I said, it's pretty easy to find out that your post has been downvoted right now, and roughly 15% of folks whose posts get downvoted do edit them.

Closing is pretty *in your face* right now; instead of seeing answers, you see a big grey box that says effectively, "NO ANSWERS FOR YOU" and includes a detailed description of *why*... We've repeatedly tweaked the guidance we give to folks whose questions are closed to *explicitly encourage editing*, with the end-result being something around 11% of closed questions get edited right now. For questions that *haven't been answered* prior to closure, that rises to 13%.

13%. The ability to get an answer depends entirely on your willingness to edit, and only 13% of people bother.

But wait, there's more! We have a review system for answers that offers a set of canned comments aimed at guiding folks who've posted very poor / non answers. Instead of notifying them that someone has flagged their post, these comments spell out specific problems that could be addressed... And something like 4% of the folks who receive these comments follow up by editing their answers.

4%, when the alternative is getting your post deleted.

I'm afraid I don't have a lot of faith in the ability of yet another signal to convince someone to fix their broken post. If downvotes aren't doing it, then it's probably not gonna happen.

Comment: It is easier to down-vote an answer than trying to revise it, especially, when it has not been approved by the original poster/others if it is workable for them or not.  Some posters on this site have not posted for, let's say, 2 years any question.  Only answers a question once in a blue moon, but keeps 'EDITING' posters questions and accumulating points.  Is that fair to the posters and the people who answer that they lose points and being discouraged to respond.  All I need to do is Edit and Brag to get 'up-voted' in some form.