# Modify the the automatic review comment to help out both reviewers and OP

Tags: discussion, review-queues

In relation to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313992/are-other-reviewers-opting-to-use-no-comment-to-avoid-confrontation-and-is-this), the currently most voted and accepted answer is **"I generally don't choose a reason"** and it's also clear that many reviewers choose the same strategy to avoid confrontation with the OP, or simple responses from OP.

My suggestion is that the **OP needs to be informed that the reviewer is trying to help** the community and not in someway targeting the OP.

There has been a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262949/question-downvote-flag-notification) [status-declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined), that could have helped a user to understand that someone else flagged, and that the reviewer is simply helping by saying *why*.

I will try to suggest this:

**Improve the review comment** to include information that the reviewer is trying to help.

I'm not good at formulating it, but something like this:

> Your question/answer is flagged by other users, the reason they flagged is
>   "......." From Review

or a generic comment, once a post has one delete vote on it:

> This post has been flagged and reviewed as off topic for this site
>   [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)*

Comment: I've got to go out, just popped online. When I return I'll have a good read thanks.

Comment: @Ms Yvette You better help me out of here.... its not going well ; ).... no comment ....

Comment: Don't worry about that. Meta is famous for that. Have a look at my posts! :)  Sometimes it's better to use the label discussion and then votes are not so harsh. As  a feature request is a more solid and defined thing, a discussion is to decided whether a request would be well received and what should be included. ps I like this idea. will be back a bit later.

Comment: Let me know what you think, I gave a second option and took out points I didn't think were helping the cause, also made it a discussion. If I've taken too many liberties, please edit them out. Sleep well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user in the review queue is voting to delete the post, and the posted comment is their reason for voting to delete the post.  The user flagging the post is just raising a probable issue; the user who's voting to delete is making a very conclusive statement that there is in fact a serious problem with the post.

The fact that the person voting to delete is seeing the post because of a flag, rather than their own initiative, doesn't change the fact that *they* are the ones conclusively stating that the post should be deleted.  That the post was flagged is just not relevant.

Yes, someone posting such a comment *is* trying to help (although they're *primarily* trying to help the site by removing crap, helping the author is a lower priority), but to try to state or imply that they're only explaining someone else's action is very wrong.

Comment: So its better to choose "no comment" and state nothing just close it..... The comment is chosen mostly to help OP and this according to me should be preferred.

Comment: @PetterFriberg "The comment is chosen mostly to help OP" Yes, *I said as much in this answer*.  But, as I also said, helping the OP *is not the top priority here*.  It's a nice benefit, but the *primary* goal is just removing the crap.  And keep in mind that the *lots* of the people posting answers this bad are never going to fix them, no matter how much you might try to help them understand what's wrong with the answer and how they could fix it.

Comment: So maybe the feature-request should be "remove review comments"?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Why would they need to be removed?  The fact that they aren't (and shouldn't be) *required* doesn't mean that they're never appropriate.

Comment: I think in "normal" case a simple user like me should know if we should select review comment or not.... (new user will select them since they try to do their best...), experienced users do not since they know the problem... Hmmm, something about this do not feel correct....

Comment: @PetterFriberg So because one user doesn't like posting comments you choose to assert that every single experienced  user never posts a comment?  Sorry, but no, you don't get to make that generalization from one single example.  You don't *have* to either always select a comment or never select a comment.  For each post in question, if you want to post a comment, you can, if you don't feel that it's appropriate in that case, then don't.  It's your decision to make.

Comment: True I'm generalizing, but I also believe that there is somewhat a truth in it. For a simple user it seem that it is preferred to make a comment to help OP, but if this cause troubles according to experienced users lets find away that it does not...

Comment: @PetterFriberg No, there is *no* truth in the statement that all experienced users never post comments.  You have a statement that *one* user doesn't post a comment in *certain situations* where he feels it wouldn't be helpful.  You're not only inappropriately generalizing one user's statements onto "all experienced users", but you're not even accurately representing that user's views.

Comment: Sorry was trying to and was trying to represent the up votes on accepted answers, thanks for you post and comments. (note I never used never : ) and note we discussed it some under the non accepted answer....

Comment: @Servy your answer here would be good as an answer to this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313992/are-other-reviewers-opting-to-use-no-comment-to-avoid-confrontation-and-is-this minus the emphasis on the flagging.

Answer (score -2):

**The review comment has sense as.**

- Information to user why post was or may be delete.
- Help them to improve to avoid that user post additional crap that need's to be reivewed.

**The review comment does not has sense as.**

- I Petter Friberg vote to delete your post and now you know why I voted like this!

This is why it should be **clear** in the review comment that reviewer is posting comment to help the user, not because he/she want to state that he/she is voting to delete.

And since a lot of [reviewer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313992/are-other-reviewers-opting-to-use-no-comment-to-avoid-confrontation-and-is-this?answertab=oldest#tab-top) are choosing to not post comment (with the risk of having to review additional crap), the comment needs to be changed or a feature of "community comment" (anonymous comment) instead of "reviewer comment" need's to be introduced.