# No notifications received for an undeleted answer and reputations got?

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I think I found a bug in SO but not sure though. Today morning I logged into SO to see my profile like I do everyday and I got 20 reputation points added to me but without any notification at the top. I thought it was weird because everytime my reputation points changes I get notified and I dint know how I got those points so, I looked in to my previous answers have not got any upvotes and also the reputation tab doesnot show any change in the graph. If I had got any upvotes I would have received a notification about it but I dint.

So I browsed other answers and I remembered one of my answer which had got link only answer got deleted few days back. So I improved that answer few days back and got to know that was one of my old [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951785/1793718) got undeleted now(since i improved the quality of the answer from link only answer). So the two upvotes that the answer had when deleted by someone gave me -20reps and now when it is undeleted it had given me the 20 reps back. But this  has to to be notified in the notification area right?

If so I think its a bug.. if not, correct me please.

Comment: When you say "Notified", you are thinking you should have seen a [+20] in the achievements in the topbar?

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes u r right..i expected that and also the undeleted answer to be notified..

Comment: you won't get notified of deletions, or undeletions at all.  That is [status-bydesign].  You probably should have been notified of the rep change, but depending on timing, the events might have canceled each other out in which you wouldn't have seen a [+20] since it only was offseting the original [-20].

Comment: http://carthik.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/feature-bug.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are looking for 2 different notifications.

First, you wanted to be notified of the undeletion.  Whether you agree with it or not, the lack of notification is an intentional design decision.  I can't find a specific post that says this for undeletion, the deletion side of it is discussed in [Will I be notified if one of my questions is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171386/will-i-be-notified-if-one-of-my-questions-is-deleted) and also the idea of closure notification is covered in [Send authors an inbox message if their question gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed).  The short version is that the designers do not believe it notifying users of bad things, only good things.  You could argue that undeletion is a **Good Thing™**, but it would also be inconsistent with the fact that you aren't notified of the original deletion.

As for the rep, you *should* have been notified of the fact that you received a +20 rep (back), however I highly doubt that it is a bug as it would have been noticed previously.  The most likely scenario is the +20 just canceled out the original -20.  Because you are only notified of **Good Things™**, you did not receive a notfication of the original -20 (but it still would have been shown in your Achievements dropdown).  If you had not opened the achievements dropdown since the post was deleted, the -20 would have still been there and the +20 just brought you back to 0 (hence no notification).  This is again by design, so it is not a bug.

In both cases, if you think the notifications should have been handled differently, you should propose separate feature requests for each.  Although I think the 2nd (notifying of the rep change) most likely a duplicate.

Comment: yes right the -20 was not shown..nor does the question deletion was notified as you mentioned..but the one who deleted had commented that it was a link only answer before deleting and from that comment notification i got to that and edited my answer..and i am sure the notification dint show up..

Comment: related: [Why downvotes and retracted upvotes are not notified immediately?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252903/839601) "We reserve real-time notifications for positive changes, not negative ones. This is a long standing design decision..."