# Why does my reputation go down 15 point?

Tags: support, reputation

I do not see any explanation at 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987441/lea-tano?tab=reputation for why my rep points went down. I used to be at 104 and then I was at 89 and I do not understand why.

Comment: 15 point is what you get when your answer gets accepted. Did one of your accepted answers get deleted/unaccepted maybe?

Comment: @gnat i did not get any notification. It is kind of similiar but not dup

Comment: this is by design, see [Why downvotes and retracted upvotes are not notified immediately?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252903/839601) "We reserve real-time notifications for positive changes, not negative ones.

This is a long standing design decision..."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your previously accepted answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27808276/timeline) was unaccepted (because the user chose a different answer as the accepted answer).

Reversal events that occur on the same day as the original event get rolled up and don't leave any trace of it in your reputation history, which is why you can't find anything there.

Comment: How can you know, without going back every question's timeline,  if an accepted question got unaccepted. It will be nice if stackoverflow lists it on your rep. I did not get any notification.

Comment: There's no other way to know that, unless you kept track of which answers were accepted and noticed one wasn't anymore. Originally all events did show up in the reputation history but Stack Exchange quickly learned that was not a good idea and was easily prone to abuse (users accepting and unaccepting flooding a user's reputation history with useless events).